# Using anchor with file include?

Tags: php, html

I try to use the anchor tag with the include I have. 
On my Index.php I got a little "nav bar" with some anchor tags.
I also included the file "text.php" in my code. This file is in the Folder "texte".
The anchor tags should bring the user to the position in text.php but it only load 404 - page not found.

How I include the file:

```
<?php include 'texte/text.php'; ?>
```

I declare my "start-word" like this:

```
<a href=“texte/text.php#InfoAnker“>Informationen</a>
```

And my anchor like this:

```
<h2 id="InfoAnker"> Informationen </h2>
```

I also tried `<a href=“#InfoAnker“>Informationen</a>` because of the include but it came out the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: try with this `<a href="#InfoAnker">Informationen</a>`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Oh im sorry, I also already tried it with #InfoAnker :)

Comment: This is not how PHP/HTML works, you should just use a achor as one always should: `#InfoAnker`.

Comment: if your on `index.php` and the anchor is on `info.php` then the link should be `info.php#InfoAnker`.

Comment: Can you be more clear? The line `<?php include 'texte/text.php'; ?>` ...this is within your `index.php` code, is that correct? Is it written inside a suitable place in your HTML markup? If that's right, then `<h2 id="InfoAnker"> Informationen </h2>` is generated somewhere within your page and sent to the browser (did you check your page source??) then it should work with `<a href="#InfoAnker">Informationen</a>` (make sure you use `"` not `“` - the are **not** the same characters, you must use the correct one)

Comment: Clicking on an anchor link should not result in a 404 error, if it's correctly defined. Even if the anchor ID doesn't actually exist in the page, it still wouldn't give a 404 - the worst that would occur would be that nothing would happen

Comment: @ADyson okey it was this problem: " not “. Thank you all :) How can I accept a comment as answer?

Comment: You can't, since it's a comment, not an answer :-). I will add a full Answer below, for you to accept...please wait a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<h2 id="InfoAnker"> Informationen </h2>` is generated somewhere within your page and sent to the browser, then an anchor link should work correctly as

```
<a href="#InfoAnker">Informationen</a>
```

One think I noticed from your example is that you should make sure you use `"` not `“` for quote marks - these are not the same characters, and you must use the correct one.

Clicking on an anchor link should not result in a 404 error, if it's correctly defined. Even if the anchor ID doesn't actually exist in the page, it still wouldn't give a 404 - the worst that would occur would be that nothing would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what @ADyson said:

Anchor links work on the *browser* side. The form `#InfoAnker` redirects to an anchor on the same page, while `texte/text.php#InfoAnker` redirects to another page. Again: on the *browser* side.

But I see, you are using includes, which work on *server* side. Normally, you don't have the same path and file structure on server and client (if your server include is located outside of wwwroot for example, but also for hiding confidential data and your program structure). This is most likely the reason why you see the 404. So if you want to access the piece of text that was included in your script, your redirect must not have a url.

But for this to work, you need to define the anchor itself, using `<h2 id="InfoAnker"> Informationen</h2>`, either in the include or in the file which includes `text.php`